# Trouble porting multiprocess future to cluster future in R

Tags: r, cluster-computing, future

I am trying to run nested futures on a cluster, works with 
minimal example, runs with cluster then multiprocess, but not with multiprocess then cluster. With multiprocess then cluster (which is what I need), I get the error:

> Error in unserialize(node$con) : cannot read from this connection

and `R` will not exit, gives error

> Error: option error has NULL value.

For the last error, I tried setting:

```
options("rstudio.errors.suppressed"=FALSE)
```

which result in a different error message:

> restarting interrupted promise evaluation

I don't think this is an `R studio` problem, get the same results running in just `R`

I tried reversing the sequence (`multiprocess-cluster` first), didn't help

```
rm(list = ls())
require(tictoc)
setwd("c:/gainr/minexample")
cl <- parallel::makePSOCKcluster(rep("localhost", 3L))
TestRun <- R6::R6Class("TestRun", 
                       public = list(
                         initialize = function() {
                         }, 
                         RunGA = function() {
                           require(stringr)
                           require(future) 
                           require(listenv) 
                           for (i in 1:2) {   
                              write(str_c("start_",i), str_c("start_",i, ".dat"))  # just write a file to see if it works

                              res <- listenv() 
                              for(n in 1:2){
                               res[[n]] %<-% self$RunNM(i,n) 
                              }
                             # wait until future resolved. 
                               while (any(!resolved(res))) {
                                 Sys.sleep(0.5)
                              }
                           }
                         }, 
                         RunNM = function(index,gen) {
                           require(stringr) 
                           write(str_c("test_", index,"_",gen), str_c("test_", index,"_",gen, ".dat"))  # just write a file to see if it works
                           Sys.sleep(2)
                         }
                       )
)  ## end TestRun R6 class

library(future)
# list of output file to remove between
fileToRemove <- c("test_1_1.dat","test_1_2.dat",
                  "test_2_1.dat","test_2_2.dat")

myExample <- TestRun$new()
# cluster then mulriprocess works

plan(list(tweak(cluster, workers = cl),tweak(multiprocess,workers=2L)))  
# implicit syntax 
tic()
a %<-% myExample$RunGA()
while (!resolved(a)) {
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
}
toc() 

if(!file.exists("test_2_2.dat")) message("Error run 1")
file.remove(fileToRemove)

### multiprocess then cluster (which is what I need), fails
plan(list(tweak(multiprocess,workers=2L),tweak(cluster, workers = cl)))  

# implicit syntax 
tic()
a %<-% myExample$RunGA()
while (!resolved(a)) {
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
}
toc()

parallel::stopCluster(cl)
rm(cl)
```

Comment: Can you turn this into a [mcve]? You can simulate expensive tasks with `Sys.sleep`.

Comment: Ralf, I'll try, unfortunately, the "models" being run are written by R code are written in Fortran, and then need to be compiled, so a fortran compiler is needed, and each model has to be in it's own directory, as it reads/writes lots of disc files. The resulting .exe file is then called by the R shell command.  I'll give it a try, in a way that doesn't require a fortran compiler, just using Sys.sleep and see if I can reproduce.

Comment: Ralf, I got some  (sort of) minimal code to reproduce the problem, still complex, but multiple configurations of nested futures, all work as expected, except mixing cluster and anything else, which seems to be generating an error (I think) that I can get at, but seems to just skip the future part that I want to run on a cluster, doesn't output the the disc file as the others do. Thanks again for any help

Comment: That's still a lot of code. Are you sure you need all the directory handling? Since I am on Linux, I would have to rewrite your code considerably ...

Comment: I'll  try taking some out, see if it has the problem without the shell command, thanks again.

Comment: Ralf, cut down, should be OS independent (except one setwd()) Thanks so much

Comment: Ralf, thanks for your time, I found an alternative way to do this, an "ad hoc" cluster,       nodes <- rep("localhost",8L)
plan(list(tweak( multiprocess,workers=2L),tweak(cluster, workers = nodes) ))      which seems to work.    Thanks again

Comment: Great that you found a solution. How about adding it as an answer?

Comment: I will, just making sure it works with the full code  (not just the minimal example).

Comment: unfortunately, I put it all back together, and is the same problem, back to the drawing board.